# Adding Gravity to Acceleration with Quaternions

Tags: c++, game-physics, physics, quaternions

I am new on this platform so please let me know if i am doing something wrong before reporting! Also, i already searched for similar problems but i could not find the answer i am looking for.

I have this problem where i need to "add" gravity component to my vector of linear accelerations, and i know this can be done with Quaternions. My vector:

```
Accelerations = [Xacc, Yacc, Zacc]
```

and a quaternions that represents my current orientation:

```
q = [w, x, y, z]
```

Let's say i start in this position:

```
q = [1,0,0,0]
```

Now of course if i move for example my smartwatch i'll get some values in my Accelerations Vector and some values in my Quaternion right?

I thought about converting my Accelerations vector into a Quaternion form:

```
AccQuat = [0, x, y, z]
```

And then make a rotation to this quaternion by the opposite of my q, so i can "translate" my Accelerations Quaternion to the Earth frame of reference q = [1,0,0,0], the converting it back into a Vector form, adding the Gravity Vector:

```
g = [0, 0, -9.81]
```

Once done, getting the "New" Vector with gravity added back into Quaternion form, rotating it to his native position and then converting it back into his vector form.

Its a little bit tricky but i think it can be done in such a way. Is this a right way to do what im trying to do? Because i have no other information other than an already Normalized Quaternion representing my position and a vector of linear Accelerations.

To multiply a Quaternions i have to apply:

```
qOut = q*p*q^-1
```

by doing 2 Quaternions multiplications right?
And if, for example, i have a quaternion representing a 90deg rotation on my Z-Axe:

```
q = [0.71, 0, 0, 0.71]
```

if i want to "Rotate back" my Accelerations Quaternion, i need to make

```
qOut = q*p*q^-1
```

but as q i need to use my "Reverse" quaternion:

```
qReverse = [0.71, 0, 0, -0.71]
```

right?

Im working with C++ to make the code work but my problem now is the mental procedure rather than coding it.
Thanks everyone for the help!

========== **EDIT** ==================

More informations:
i have a fixed coordinates system called World (0,0,0) always parallel to my floor, my Quaternion rotations are for a system called "0" that refers to this World, they have the same centre in (0,0,0).
Maybe this can explain better:

[image]

World is Black, 0 is Blue One.

Lets suppose that my blue axis are my 3 components in the acceleration vector.
I thought about converting them into a Quaternion by simply adding a constant = 0 as w, then rotating them with the Quaternion formula (where q is reverse of my quaternion that i got from the data):

```
f = q*p*q^-1
```

So they can coincide with the Black system.
From this add the gravity component from the Z axis as it is // to the floor, then rotating my "New Accelerations quaternion" to his original position with the same formula but inverted q. In the end i want to get my Accelerations vector with Gravity added that's all. I thought it could be done with quaternions. Hope this can explain better, forgive me if im repeating same things but im also new to this argument.

Comment: The answer to this will depend on the coordinate frames of the vectors you are working with and the quaternion convention you are using. E.g., is the Acceleration vector in BODY coordinates? Are you trying to get a result in BODY frame or EARTH frame? Is the quaternion a right-chain or left-chain convention? Is the quaternion right-handed or left-handed? Tell us what you know about any of this, and then we can suggest algorithms to use. If you don't know, then it may be a bit of trial and error to figure things out.

Comment: Quaternions (unit quaternions in particular) are used to represent **rotations**, not accelerations (which are of course three-dimensional vectors).  You can of course use accelerometer data to obtain an **orientation**, which is yet a different beast (more than one rotation can produce the same orientation).  You can’t just combine all these types with padding/subsetting.

Comment: @JamesTursa  I added an Edit tying to explain more!

Comment: @mattiway Yes you have the correct idea. The only caveat is your triple operation q * p * q^-1 assumes a left-chain convention for the coordinate transformation. You should spot check this with some specific numeric values to make sure the results are as expected. It not, then you might have to use a q^-1 * p * q operation instead. Bottom line is your understanding of the algorithms involved is correct, but the location of the q^-1 in the triple product may need to change depending on the underlying quaternion convention.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, so the procedure is correct, i just need to figure out how to deal with the multiplications and test it on field let's say.. Indeed i have a final question: if i add the gravity component from my accelerations, when i rotate back my vector in "Quaternion" form i should have it like this: [0, AccX, AccY, AccZ], but what if my w isnt 0? How can i put it back in a "Vector" form, so i can access to AccX, AccY, AccZ? Sorry if my terms aren't really correct...

Comment: The result of a q^-1 * p * q or q * p * q^-1 operation where the w (scalar) part of p is 0 is mathematically guaranteed to have a resulting w part exactly 0.  In practice you will often get a very small residual value for w because of floating point arithmetic effects, but this can be ignored. Just pick off the vector part of the resulting quaternion for your answer. If the resulting w part is *not* small, then that would indicate you have an error in your quaternion multiplication code.

Comment: @JamesTursa Thank You very much! I Finally understood!